# How to make a SQL query for last transaction of every account?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Say I have a table "transactions" that has columns "acct_id" "trans_date" and "trans_type" and I want to filter this table so that I have just the last transaction for each account.  Clearly I could do something like

```
SELECT acct_id, max(trans_date) as trans_date  
FROM transactions GROUP BY acct_id;
```

but then I lose my trans_type.  I could then do a second SQL call with my list of dates and account id's and get my trans_type back but that feels very cludgy since it means either sending data back and forth to the sql server or it means creating a temporary table.

Is there a way to do this with a single query, hopefully a generic method that would work with mysql, postgres, sql-server, and oracle.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is an example of a [greatest-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) query.  This question comes up several times per week on StackOverflow.  In addition to the subquery solutions given by other folks, here's my preferred solution, which uses no subquery, `GROUP BY`, or CTE:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM transactions t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions t2
  ON (t1.acct_id = t2.acct_id AND t1.trans_date < t2.trans_date)
WHERE t2.acct_id IS NULL;
```

In other words, return a row such that no other row exists with the same `acct_id` and a greater `trans_date`.

This solution assumes that `trans_date` is unique for a given account, otherwise ties may occur and the query will return all tied rows.  But this is true for all the solutions given by other folks too.

I prefer this solution because I most often work on MySQL, which doesn't optimize `GROUP BY` very well.  So this outer join solution usually proves to be better for performance.

Answer (score 13):

This works on SQL Server...

```
SELECT acct_id, trans_date, trans_type
FROM transactions a
WHERE trans_date = (
   SELECT MAX( trans_date )
   FROM transactions b
   WHERE a.acct_id = b.acct_id
)
```

Comment: This is my favourite. You can also have your where clause be `NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM transaction z WHERE a.acct_id = z.acct_id AND z.trans_date > a.trans_date)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
WITH 
LastTransaction AS
(
    SELECT acct_id, max(trans_date) as trans_date  
    FROM transactions 
    GROUP BY acct_id
),
AllTransactions AS
(
    SELECT acct_id, trans_date, trans_type
    FROM transactions 
)
SELECT *
FROM AllTransactions
INNER JOIN LastTransaction
    ON AllTransactions.acct_id = LastTransaction.acct_id
    AND AllTransactions.trans_date  = LastTransaction.trans_date
```

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL 5.7, still in wide use, doesn't support `WITH` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.acct_id, t.trans_type, tm.trans_date
from transactions t
inner join (
    SELECT acct_id, max(trans_date) as trans_date  
    FROM transactions 
    GROUP BY acct_id;
) tm on t.acct_id = tm.acct_id and t.trans_date = tm.trans_date
```

Comment: That's what I fixed, left out trans_date in ON clause.