# SQL update table, for multiple company, store, POS when new transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

Looking for how to update Table2 when a new transaction arrives in Table1.

I´m picking up data from Table1 and inserting into Table2.

```
SELECT distinct Company, StoreNo, POS FROM Table1
```

Result

```
Company1, S0001, P0001
Company1, S0001, P0002
Company1, S0002, P0003
Company1, S0002, P0004
Company2, S0001, P0001
Company2, S0001, P0002
Company2, S0002, P0003
Company2, S0002, P0004
```

Transaction number starts at 1 for each POS.

I want to update Table2 incrementally, only when transaction number in Table1 is greater then in Table2. But I´m having problems solving this, since the UPDATE needs to be in each case for each company, store, POS.

Was looking at this: [How to make a SQL query for last transaction of every account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505549/how-to-make-a-sql-query-for-last-transaction-of-every-account) but not really getting there.

Comment: Ended up doing a stored procedure and inserting manually into '@TableName'. Ex. SELECT company, StoreNo FROM @TableName

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008 R2 :
Try This Trigger Demo:
You can achieve this by using Trigger
Please look into one simple Trigger demo.

```
/*Create Demo Table.*/
CREATE TABLE A (RNO INT)
CREATE TABLE B (RNO INT)

/*Craete Demo Trigger*/
CREATE TRIGGER MYTRI ON A
FOR INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO B SELECT * FROM inserted i  
GO

/*Insert statement */
INSERT INTO A VALUES (1)

/*Check Result*/
SELECT *FROM A
SELECT *FROM B
```