# Finding row of "duplicate" data with greatest value

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table setup as follows:

```
Key || Code || Date
5       2      2018
5       1      2017
8       1      2018
8       2      2017
```

I need to retrieve only the key and code where:

```
Code=2 AND Date > the other record's date
```

So based on this data above, I need to retrieve:

```
Key 5 with code=2
```

Key 8 does not meet the criteria since code 2's date is lower than code 1's date

I tried joining the table on itself but this returned incorrect data

```
Select key,code 
from data d1
Join data d2 on d1.key = d2.key
Where d1.code = 2 and d1.date > d2.date
```

This method returned data with incorrect values and wrong data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a SQL query for last transaction of every account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505549/how-to-make-a-sql-query-for-last-transaction-of-every-account)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want this:

```
select d.*
from data d
where d.code = 2 and
      d.date > (select d2.date
                from data d2
                where d2.key = d.key and d2.code = 1
               );
```

If you just want the key, I would go for aggregation:

```
select d.key
from data d
group by d.key
having max(case when d2.code = 2 then date end) > max(case when d2.code <> 2 then date end);
```

Comment: This is probably the answer, idk why I didn't think of this. Will test and mark as answer if this works. Thanks.

Comment: I can't believe I've never seen this syntax before. +1

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number`, u can select rows with dates in ascending order. This is based on your sample data, selecting 2 rows

```
DECLARE @table TABLE ([key] INT, code INT, DATE INT)

INSERT @table
SELECT 5, 2, 2018

UNION ALL

SELECT 5, 2, 2018

UNION ALL

SELECT 8, 1, 2018

UNION ALL

SELECT 8, 2, 2017

SELECT [key], code, DATE
FROM (
    SELECT [key], code, DATE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY [key], code ORDER BY DATE
            ) rn
    FROM @table
    ) x
WHERE rn = 2
```